# How to activate Steam Overlay on non Steam games?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, steam

I was trying to get my friend to watch me on Minecraft, (I launched it through Steam), and it said that it was waiting for my broadcast to start. (No overlay)

How do I add the Steam overlay on my Minecraft?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add Minecraft as a non-steam game.

Go to Steam and click "Add Non-Steam Game to My Library", then select Minecraft or find Minecraft.exe.

Comment: Already done it. thanks for help, i guess? Edit: Im talking about the launcher version.

Comment: that's probably the problem.  The overlay is probably attaching to the launcher, and not carrying forward to the actual game.  For Minecraft, you might be better off using another broadcasting service, although I can't really recommend one.

Comment: I attached the Steam Overlay to the Launcher and it migrates directly inside the game and in every window opened through the launcher. Try with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe` for the "target area" and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft` for the "Start In" area.

Comment: @gatherer818 I have no idea what to use. besides im using steam so i can't send him a link most likely. Also yes the overlay is attaching to the launcher and i was asking how to fix this.

Comment: @hiru How? my minecraft is currently named "malware" (Because its the launcher downloaded version)